# How to make repeating matrix with increasing number without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to make repeating matrix. And one condition is element increases in constant with every repeated step.

For example,
with `[a b]`, I want to make multiple arrays like `[a b a+D b+D a+2D b+2D a+3D b+3D]` and `[a b a b a+C b+C a+C b+C]`. (`C` and `D` are constant)

Since eliminating for loop is essential, are there any special functions (like `repmat`) or tricks to make those kind of matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of `repmat` and `reshape`, you can achieve it as follows:

```
A = [1 2];
n = 5;
D = 10;
B = reshape(repmat(A(:), 1, n) + D*(0:(n-1)), 1, [])
```

**pre 2016b** (does not allow implicit expansion)

```
B = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, repmat(A(:), 1, n), D*(0:(n-1))), 1, [])
```